# How to understand the location of the largest number out of an input series?

Tags: java

I do not understand how to locate the largest number from a series of numbers entered by a user.

I created a MaxSentinel.java that prompts the user to enter numbers one by one. MaxSentinel breaks its cycle when a negative one is detected.

I need to modify the previous code and create MaxSentinel2.java.

The task at hand is to check for a valid first entry. Then allow the user to enter as many numbers as desired.

If an invalid number is entered, print "Invalid entry."
Prompt the user again until a valid number is entered.

Once a negative one is detected, the program stops and prints the largest number entered.

---

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MaxSentinel2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("This program allows you to enter a series of numbers.");
        System.out.println("Enter -1 when you are finished entering your numbers and");
        System.out.println("the program will print the largest number entered.");
        System.out.println("Enter your first number, please.");
        System.out.print("Next integer (-1 to quit)? ");
        input.nextInt();
        while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid response.");
            System.out.println("Enter your first number, please.");
            input.nextInt();
        }
        int number = input.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;

        while (number != -1) {
            sum += number;
            while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid response.");
                System.out.println("Enter your first number, please.");
                input.nextInt();
            }
            number = input.nextInt();
        }
        int max = 0;
        if (max < number) {
            max++;
        }
        System.out.println("The largest number entered was: " + max);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to maintain a `max` variable. And as the numbers come, update this `max` value if the incoming number is bigger than `max`

Answer (score 3):

Below section does not make any sense. You can remove this part:

```
    input.nextInt();
    while (!input.hasNextInt()) ;
    {
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid response.");
        System.out.println("Enter your first number, please.");
        input.nextInt();
    }
```

also, why do you need to find the total sum of all numbers? I guess it's a copying mistake. You can remove `sum` variable as well.

```
int max = 0;
if (max < number) 
{
  max++;  
}
```

above section can be simply replaced by using `Math.max()` function

```
System.out.println("The largest number entered was: " + Math.max(max, number));
```

If you want to identify the largest number in the entire number sequence, you need to go through the entire number sequence in order to identify the largest number. That means, the largest number can only be printed when you are done with looping(outside the while loop).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // How to use program
    System.out.println("This program allows you to enter a series of numbers.\n" +
            "Enter -1 when you are finished entering your numbers and \n" +
            "the program will print the largest number entered. \n" +
            "Please enter your numbers(-1 to quit) : ");
    int max = 0;
    try {
        int userInput = input.nextInt();

        while (userInput != -1) {
            max = Math.max(max, userInput);
            userInput = input.nextInt();
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Program exiting as input was invalid!");
    }
    System.out.println("The largest number entered was: " + max);
}
```

Comment: @Abra edited the answer just to handle `InputMismatchException`. There could be numerous reasons the program could fail, but OP is only interested in the program workflow as it is a homework assignment.

Comment: A quote from the question: _If an invalid number is entered, print "Invalid entry." Prompt the user again until a valid number is entered._ Your code does not prompt the user again, it simply exits.

Answer (score 1):

to store all entered values you need to create an arrayList for finding the Max input number, and to check whether the input is correct and its number you need to add a `try-catch` block , and by using stream you can find the max value which was entered.

**note:** you can also use for loop to find the max value by reading following link:

> [Java – Finding minimum and maximum values in an array](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/java-finding-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-an-array/)

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("This program allows you to enter a series of numbers.");
System.out.println("Enter -1 when you are finished entering your numbers and");
System.out.println("the program will print the largest number entered.");
System.out.println("Enter your first number, please.");

ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

String data = "";
while (!data.equals("-1")) {
    System.out.print("Next integer (-1 to quit)? ");
    data = input.next();
    
    try {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(data); 
        numbers.add(number);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid response.");
    }
}
int max = numbers.stream().mapToInt(v -> v).max().getAsInt();
System.out.println("The largest number entered was: " + max);
```

You can also solve the problem simply without using `ArrayList`, and `stream`:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("This program allows you to enter a series of numbers.");
System.out.println("Enter -1 when you are finished entering your numbers and");
System.out.println("the program will print the largest number entered.");
System.out.println("Enter your first number, please.");

String data = "";
int max = 0;
while (!data.equals("-1")) {
    System.out.print("Next integer (-1 to quit)? ");
    data = input.next();
    
    try {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(data);
        if(number > max) {
            max = number;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid response.");
    }
}

System.out.println("The largest number entered was: " + max);
```

Comment: Why not just keep track of the largest number entered inside the `while` loop? I have a feeling that the stream API may be a bit advanced for the OP. Also, I don't think there is a requirement to save all the numbers entered by the user.

Comment: @Abra yes, its also possible to keep track of max value inside for loop, and you are correct its also simple without using stream.